# How to avoid "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a bot that runs on Azure + Bot Framework + LUIS (via LuisDialog).

If the user happens to send two messages in a quick succession (before the bot has a chance to answer), they see this error message on their Facebook Messenger or web embed:

> **Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.**

When debugging through bot channel emulator, I see that the error is this:

> "text": "Error: Response status code does not indicate success: 429
>   (Too Many Requests).    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisService.d__4.MoveNext()

The end of the stack trace shows that the error originated at this line in my MessageController.cs:

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new LuisRootDialogEnglish());
```

This is weird because I'm using a paid version of LUIS which allows up to 10 calls per second.

In any case, I tried wrapping the whole code in MessageController.cs into a `try/catch` block, and returning this value regardless of an exception:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Still, the users see the error message "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" which basically means there is an unhandled exception.

How can I prevent this message from being shown to users, or catch the exception?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The message is sent to the user in `PostUnhandledExceptionToUserTask` only because the exception has escaped the root dialog A.  You can avoid this situation by preventing unhandled exceptions from escaping the root dialog A.

One option is to add a different root dialog B that simply calls your dialog A and then simply ignores the `IAwaitable<R>` result that is passed to the `ResumeAfter<R>` callback.

`Chain.DefaultIfException` provides an implementation of dialog B.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DefaultIfException` functionality for Bot Framework to internally handle the exception.

It looks like this:

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(
   activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog().DefaultIfException()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get an 403 or 429, it could be "out of quota" or "Too many request" respectively, in the first case you must create a key again and asign to your LUIS App, the first-1000 endpoint queries are free and it will be refreshed every month, you must use it wisely or you have to use a Paid tier.

For the second case you have also a limit for the request, see the [Boundaries documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries)

Here you can find Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-azure-subscription) about this.