# BotBuilder C# Catching "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" from a Scorable Dialogs

Tags: c#, botframework

Bot Builder C#, version : 3.15.3 Net Framework : 4.7

Azure Web Application / Channel Bot Registration

My bot show 'Sorry, my bot code is having an issue' when i use a global message handlers (Scorable) after a no use for long time.

I have 2 global message handlers they was : cancelScorable and HelpScorable.

I'm using those article to build my handlers :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-global-handlers?view=azure-bot-service-3.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-scorable-dialogs?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

I know this article : [How to avoid "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" in Microsoft Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609638/how-to-avoid-sorry-my-bot-code-is-having-an-issue-in-microsoft-bot-framework)
But it's not what i'm looking for i have already implemented the "LogIfException());"  on my root dialog.  Asking if exist a same way to handling or logging exception provided by the scorable dialogs.

In the picture you can view the 2 call to my reset scorable **/reset** and you can see after 4hours of inactivity the exception apears : 
[image]

**Edit** : *I have the same message with the use off existing framework scorable* ==> **/deleteprofile**

[image]

**Edit** : For information thoses exception apears on **teams channel**, curently i'm trying to reproduce thoses on WebChat, DirectLine in a small project with the use off sample Bot Builder Application.

Comment: It would be good to know if the exception is here because of the inactivity of because you are doing it twice. Do you have implemented application insights log?

Comment: The exception it's due to the inactivity, in other case i call 2,3 or 4 the reset request and doesn't have the exception.

Comment: Could you please post a minimal reproducible for this so we can recreate your issue?

Comment: You can also register a custom PostUnhandledExceptionToUser: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4486#issuecomment-387193321

Comment: Thx for your response Eric i'm looking this issues and implement a custom PostUnhandledExceptionToUser. Mark I'm trying to reproduce this on simple Bot Builder Solution and share this with you. 
Thx all for response.